# Log a message with each HTTP Cloud Function error response

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I'm using google cloud HTTP functions and it seems like cloud functions automatically writes a single log line for each response. When an error occurs, I'd have expected perhaps a snippet of the body response to be logged, but there's nothing besides the status code and response size.

Here's some example code:

```golang
func init() {
    functions.HTTP("Scrape", ScrapeHTTP)
}

func Scrape(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := validateRequestData(r)
    if err != nil {
        // Doesn't actually log "my error message" in `textPayload` on logs.
        http.Error(w, "my error message", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
}
```

Here's an example of what gets logged:

```json
{
  "insertId": "65aea4130000c5a9b9b6bad2",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestUrl": "<removed>",
    "requestSize": "1355",
    "status": 500,
    "responseSize": "782",
    "userAgent": "Google-Cloud-Tasks",
    "latency": "0.143171908s",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "<removed>",
      "location": "<removed>",
      "revision_name": "<removed>",
      "service_name": "scrape",
      "configuration_name": "scrape"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-01-22T17:21:22.905611Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
    "instanceId": "<removed>"
  },
  "logName": "projects/<removed>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "trace": "<removed>",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-01-22T17:21:23.141132352Z",
  "spanId": "1278497214486517307"
}
```

I would have expected "my error message" to appear somewhere in the logs but it doesn't.
Is there a way to get that logged besides manually logging the error using the logging library?

When a function times out, the same automatic log response line has a `textPayload` with the message: "The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout.", so perhaps there's a way of passing a `textPayload` to `http.Error`?

Comment: Google is logging what your application generates. If you want to change what is logged, modify your app's logger or create an additional log entry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @JohnHanley! I think I know how to create an additional log entry, but how do I change the app's logger?

Comment: Consult the documentation for the logger you configured. If you did not configure one, then Google is just logging print statements that your program writes to the console. When writing good software, your code should handle all errors/warnings and not rely on default libraries to do it for you.

Comment: Aha, now I see that `http.Error` simply calls `fmt.Fprintln(w, error)`, which is what results in the log line being added. I thought there was actually some magic going on with cloud functions. Thanks for the explanation, John!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what `http.Error` does:

```golang
// Error replies to the request with the specified error message and HTTP code.
// It does not otherwise end the request; the caller should ensure no further
// writes are done to w.
// The error message should be plain text.
func Error(w ResponseWriter, error string, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, error)
}
```

There's actually no special magic logging from google cloud functions, the log line I'm seeing is actually coming from `fmt.Fprintln(w, error)`.

The solution is to actually simply write your own error function that writes [structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_structured_logs). It's unfortunate that this practice is never mentioned anywhere in the documentation, which uses `http.Error` everywhere.

Thanks a lot for the hint, @JohnHanley!

Comment: Very useful answer for future readers.